# can we run generated C code by labview in the raspberry Pi2?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi2, labview

Can we run generated C code by labVIEW in the raspberry Pi2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't - at least officially.

But someone is working on that.
Give a look to [this](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW-Idea-Exchange/LabVIEW-for-Raspberry-Pi/idi-p/2082026/) thread on Labview Idea Exchange forum.

Here are some interesting projects (cited in the thread):

- [LINX 3.0 - LabVIEW for BeagleBone and Raspberry Pi](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=blog:users:makerhub:2016-04-07-linx-3)
- [LabVIEW VIP package file for the Raspberry Pi Compatible Compiler for LabVIEW](https://github.com/filipealtoe/LabVIEWforRasPiVIPM)